# How do I selectively change lifetime scope during Autofac assembly scanning and registration?

Tags: c#, singleton, autofac

I have a class that uses AutoFac to build a container from the assemblies in the binary folder. This essentially iterates over the dll's and registers classes with an interface:

```
    private static void RegisterAssembly(ContainerBuilder builder, string assemblyNamePattern)
    {
        // Get the path to the currently executing assembly. We will load dll's from here only.
        var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path))
            return;

        // Get a list of all the assemblies in this folder
        var assembliesToRegister = (Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, assemblyNamePattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                .Select(Assembly.LoadFrom)
                .ToArray());

        // Register the dll's
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembliesToRegister).AsImplementedInterfaces();
    }
```

That's working fine and I can create instances of the classes I need. The problem I have is that there are couple of these classes that are singletons (Redis caching for example), so need to be registered as such. In code, they're defined using the Lazy<>:

```
    private static readonly Lazy<CacheManager> _instance = new Lazy<CacheManager>(() => new CacheManager());
    public static ICacheManager Instance
    {
        get { return _instance.Value; }
    }
```

What I am wondering is whether there is some way to tell AutoFac that certain classes need to be registered as singletons. I'm guessing I can go through the container after it's been built and change specific definitions to be singletons, but it would be far more reliable if I could get Autofac to do it automatically at registration.

Comment: Which verison of Autofac do you use?

Comment: Version 3.5.2 (sorry, should have added that to the post). I've made some progress in that I am now registering the assemblies and using <Except> to exclude the singleton classes. I then register these separately as SingleInstance().ExternallyOwned(). Not a great solution, but learning fast!

Comment: Using the LINQ to include/exclude certain types is actually the answer to your question - you should post that and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a cheap solution, when the DLL's are scanned, you can exclude one or more interfaces:

```
        // Register the dll's, except the singleton ones.
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembliesToRegister)
                .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                .Except<IOne>()
                .Except<ITwo>();
```

This allows for everything except the singletons to be registered automatically. Next, register the singletons:

```
AddSingletonInstance<IOne>(builder, assembliesToRegister, "OneType");
AddSingletonInstance<ITwo>(builder, assembliesToRegister, "TwoType");
```

This relies on a generic method that scans the assembly list created earlier:

```
    private static void AddSingletonInstance<T>(ContainerBuilder builder, Assembly[] assembliesToRegister, string typeName)
    {
        var singletonType = (from asm in assembliesToRegister
                        from tt in asm.DefinedTypes
                        where tt.Name == typeName
                        select tt).FirstOrDefault();

        if (singletonType != null)
            builder.RegisterType(singletonType).As<T>().SingleInstance().ExternallyOwned();
    }
```

It's not ideal, but it works.